# How to wrap a callback function in a Parse.Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, parse-server

I have a function:

```
function foo(aString, function(err, callback) {
   //does stuff
}
```

I need to call that function from the middle of a long series of Parse.Promises.

How can I wrap it in a Parse.Promise?

I've tried:

```
//...
return new Parse.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            foo(thatString, function(err, data) {
                if(err) return reject(err);
                resolve(data);
            });
        });
}).then(function(data) {
//...
```

and other variations like `Parse.Promise.as()` instead of `new Parse.Promise()`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And what would not work with that?

Comment: It just hangs. Never reaches the inside of foo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but Parse's promise constructor doesn't take resolve / reject functions.  Instead, have your wrapper build and return a promise without params, then invoke that promise's `resolve()` or `reject()` methods in the wrapped function's callback, like this:

```
var wrappedFoo = function(aString) {
    var promise = new Parse.Promise();
    foo(aString, function(err, data) {
        if (err) { promise.reject(err); }
        promise.resolve(data);
    });
    return promise;
};
```

Call it like this:

```
wrappedFoo("bar").then(function(data) {
    // data will be the data passed to the foo callback
}, function(err) {
    // likewise for err
});
```

Comment: Thanks @danh!  Worked like a charm.